# What termios settings cause endpoint to get garbled serial?

Tags: terminal, tty, serial-port, serial-console

I have two endpoints. One is Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu) and the other is a small AR9331 router (running OpenWRT and has 16550 chip). They are connected over a USB-to-Serial connection.

**Sending from AR9331 to WSL works as expected.**

WSL Console:

```
~/openwrt_master$ cat /dev/ttyS5

HELLOTOALL

HELLOTOALL

HELLOTOALL
```

AR9331 Console:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# echo "HELLOTOALL" > /dev/ttyATH0
root@OpenWrt:~# echo "HELLOTOALL" > /dev/ttyATH0
root@OpenWrt:~# echo "HELLOTOALL" > /dev/ttyATH0
```

**Sending from WSL to AR9331 does not work as expected, it appears garbled or out of order.**

WSL Console:

```
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
~/openwrt_master$ echo "ILIKECHICKEN" > /dev/ttyS5
```

AR9331 Console:

```
ILIKECHICKEN

IKECHICKEN

ILIKECHICKEN

I

ILIKECHICKEN

I

ILIKECHICKEN

I

ILIKECHICKEN

IKECHICKEN

ILIKECHICKEN
```

AR9331 TTY settings:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# stty -F /dev/ttyATH0 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

WSL TTY settings:

```
~/openwrt_master$ stty -F /dev/ttyS5 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = <undef>; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

I tried messing with canonical mode, but it did not appear to change anything.

Comment: Please copy&paste all text to your question **as text** and format it as code instead of showing screenshots. Instead of repeatedly sending "HELLO" I suggest to use different unique strings. This will make it clearer which characters get lost or duplicated. Do both both serial interfaces use/require the same signal voltage?

Comment: Given that you send 7 HELLO strings and receive 7 H characters my **guess** is speed, there is not enough hardware buffering on the router to absorb the burst of characters and there is no hardware flow control. I see no garbled or out of order characters, just missing ones.

Comment: Now I can read the text, try one or both of 'stty crtscts` and `stty -clocal` to enable hardware flow control assuming your USB <-> Serial supports it.